# Changing date format in R

Tags: r, date, format, strptime, r-faq

I have some very simple data in R that needs to have its date format changed:

```
 date midpoint
1   31/08/2011   0.8378
2   31/07/2011   0.8457
3   30/06/2011   0.8147
4   31/05/2011   0.7970
5   30/04/2011   0.7877
6   31/03/2011   0.7411
7   28/02/2011   0.7624
8   31/01/2011   0.7665
9   31/12/2010   0.7500
10  30/11/2010   0.7734
11  31/10/2010   0.7511
12  30/09/2010   0.7263
13  31/08/2010   0.7158
14  31/07/2010   0.7110
15  30/06/2010   0.6921
16  31/05/2010   0.7005
17  30/04/2010   0.7113
18  31/03/2010   0.7027
19  28/02/2010   0.6973
20  31/01/2010   0.7260
21  31/12/2009   0.7154
22  30/11/2009   0.7287
23  31/10/2009   0.7375
```

Rather than `%d/%m/%Y`, I would like it in the standard R format of `%Y-%m-%d`

How can I make this change? I have tried:

```
nzd$date <- format(as.Date(nzd$date), "%Y/%m/%d")
```

But that just cut off the year and added zeros to the day:

```
 [1] "0031/08/20" "0031/07/20" "0030/06/20" "0031/05/20" "0030/04/20"
 [6] "0031/03/20" "0028/02/20" "0031/01/20" "0031/12/20" "0030/11/20"
 [11] "0031/10/20" "0030/09/20" "0031/08/20" "0031/07/20" "0030/06/20"
 [16] "0031/05/20" "0030/04/20" "0031/03/20" "0028/02/20" "0031/01/20"
 [21] "0031/12/20" "0030/11/20" "0031/10/20" "0030/09/20" "0031/08/20"
 [26] "0031/07/20" "0030/06/20" "0031/05/20" "0030/04/20" "0031/03/20"
 [31] "0028/02/20" "0031/01/20" "0031/12/20" "0030/11/20" "0031/10/20"
 [36] "0030/09/20" "0031/08/20" "0031/07/20" "0030/06/20" "0031/05/20"
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 80, accepted):

There are two steps here:

- Parse the data. Your example is not fully reproducible, is the data in a file, or the variable in a text or factor variable?  Let us assume the latter, then if you data.frame is called X, you can do

> ```
>  X$newdate <- strptime(as.character(X$date), "%d/%m/%Y")
> ```

Now the `newdate` column should be of type `Date`.

- Format the data.  That is a matter of calling `format()` or `strftime()`:

> ```
>  format(X$newdate, "%Y-%m-%d")
> ```

A more complete example:

```
R> nzd <- data.frame(date=c("31/08/2011", "31/07/2011", "30/06/2011"), 
+                    mid=c(0.8378,0.8457,0.8147))
R> nzd
        date    mid
1 31/08/2011 0.8378
2 31/07/2011 0.8457
3 30/06/2011 0.8147
R> nzd$newdate <- strptime(as.character(nzd$date), "%d/%m/%Y")
R> nzd$txtdate <- format(nzd$newdate, "%Y-%m-%d")
R> nzd
        date    mid    newdate    txtdate
1 31/08/2011 0.8378 2011-08-31 2011-08-31
2 31/07/2011 0.8457 2011-07-31 2011-07-31
3 30/06/2011 0.8147 2011-06-30 2011-06-30
R>
```

The difference between columns three and four is the type: `newdate` is of class `Date` whereas `txtdate` is character.

Comment: hmm, this seems extremely complicated for a noob. I ended up just changing the formatting in excel and reading the csv file back into R. I was wanting to know how to easily change it in R in case I had a much bigger file, but this doesn't seem nearly as easy as it should be. That's no slight on your solution, I was just hoping it was much simpler (possibly a way to convert the original column without creating a new one). Is there a way to change the class first and then format it?

Comment: @Yuri - That's essentially what Dirk's answer was showing you how to do, though he created some new columns along the way so you can easily see what's happening "under the hood". I recommend walking through his example line by line, inserting a `str(x)` in between each line so you can see the differences in action.

Comment: @Chase Thanks I do appreciate the extra column for pedagogical purposes and it helped me see the class difference as well as the format; so thanks for that! Good to know the extra step with the additional column isn't strictly necessary. Thanks to you both!

Answer (score 17):

```
nzd$date <- format(as.Date(nzd$date), "%Y/%m/%d")
```

In the above piece of code, there are two mistakes. First of all, when you are reading `nzd$date` inside `as.Date` you are not mentioning in what format you are feeding it the `date`. So, it tries it's default set format to read it. If you see the `help` doc, `?as.Date` you will see

> format
>       A character string. If not specified, it will try "%Y-%m-%d"
>       then "%Y/%m/%d" on the first non-NA element, and give an error
>       if neither works. Otherwise, the processing is via strptime

The second mistake is: even though you would like to read it in `%Y-%m-%d` format, inside `format` you wrote `"%Y/%m/%d"`.

Now, the correct way of doing it is:

```
> nzd <- data.frame(date=c("31/08/2011", "31/07/2011", "30/06/2011"), 
+                                       mid=c(0.8378,0.8457,0.8147))
> nzd
        date    mid
1 31/08/2011 0.8378
2 31/07/2011 0.8457
3 30/06/2011 0.8147
> nzd$date <- format(as.Date(nzd$date, format = "%d/%m/%Y"), "%Y-%m-%d")
> head(nzd)
        date    mid
1 2011-08-31 0.8378
2 2011-07-31 0.8457
3 2011-06-30 0.8147
```

Answer (score 8):

You could also use the `parse_date_time` function from the `lubridate` package:

```
library(lubridate)
day<-"31/08/2011"
as.Date(parse_date_time(day,"dmy"))
[1] "2011-08-31"
```

`parse_date_time` returns a POSIXct object, so we use `as.Date` to get a date object. The first argument of `parse_date_time` specifies a date vector, the second argument specifies the order in which your format occurs. The `orders` argument makes `parse_date_time` very flexible.

Answer (score 3):

After reading your data in via a `textConnection`, the following seems to work:

```
dat <- read.table(textConnection(txt), header = TRUE)
dat$date <- strptime(dat$date, format= "%d/%m/%Y")
format(dat$date, format="%Y-%m-%d")

> format(dat$date, format="%Y-%m-%d")
 [1] "2011-08-31" "2011-07-31" "2011-06-30" "2011-05-31" "2011-04-30" "2011-03-31"
 [7] "2011-02-28" "2011-01-31" "2010-12-31" "2010-11-30" "2010-10-31" "2010-09-30"
[13] "2010-08-31" "2010-07-31" "2010-06-30" "2010-05-31" "2010-04-30" "2010-03-31"
[19] "2010-02-28" "2010-01-31" "2009-12-31" "2009-11-30" "2009-10-31"

> str(dat)
'data.frame':   23 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ date    : POSIXlt, format: "2011-08-31" "2011-07-31" "2011-06-30" ...
 $ midpoint: num  0.838 0.846 0.815 0.797 0.788 ...
```

Comment: I do have a question about POSIXlt in data frames as is referenced here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3355107/possibly-inconsistent-behavior-in-qplot

When I try to plot the date as an x axis in ggplot, I receive this error --  

Error in if (length(range) == 1 || diff(range) == 0) { : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed -- 

How would I get this in POSIXct?

Comment: @Yuri - something like `as.POSIXct(otherStuffHere)` will probably work. Thanks for that link, I wasn't aware of those issues raised by Hadley.

Answer (score 3):

This is really easy using package lubridate. All you have to do is tell R what format your date is already in. It then converts it into the standard format

`nzd$date <- dmy(nzd$date)`

that's it.

Answer (score 3):

Using one line to convert the dates to preferred format:

```
nzd$date <- format(as.Date(nzd$date, format="%d/%m/%Y"),"%Y/%m/%d")
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe that

```
nzd$date <- as.Date(nzd$date, format = "%d/%m/%Y")
```

is sufficient.

Comment: Agreed, but it relies on _magic_ (the default formatting) so it is beneficial to show the distinct steps.

Answer (score 0):

If your input have a consistent date format, you may try a simple workaround:

```
sapply(date, function(x){paste(strsplit(x, '/')[[1]][c(3,2,1)], collapse = '/')})
```

Comment: To deal with NAs, you may need:

`sapply(date, function(x){ifelse(is.na(x),NA,paste(strsplit(x, '/')[[1]][c(3,2,1)], collapse = '/'))})`