# issues with formatting a column with date in r

Tags: r, date

I'm having an issue trying to format date in r... tried the following codes
`rdate<-as.Date(dusted$time2,"%d/%m/%y")` and also the recommendations on this stackoverflow question [Changing date format in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7439977/changing-date-format-in-r) but still couldn't get it to work.

`geov<-dusted
geov$newdate <- strptime(as.character(geov$time2), "%d/%m/%Y")`

all i'm getting is NA for the whole column for date. This are daily values, i would love if r can read them. Data available here https://www.dropbox.com/s/awstha04muoz66y/dusted.txt?dl=0

Comment: The dates in your dataset are separated by hyphens, while you have specified slashes. Another problem is you're using `%Y` which is for 4 digit years. For 2 digit years, you need to use `%y`.

Comment: Thanks @Teja, that was helpful...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To convert to date, as long as you successfully imported the data already into a data frame such as `dusted` or `geov`, and have `time2` holding dates as strings resembling `10-27-06`, try:

```
geov$time2 = as.Date(geov$time2, "%m-%d-%y")
```

- equal sign `=` used just to save on typing. It is equivalent to `<-`, so you can still use `<-` if you prefer
- this stores the converted dates right back into `geov$time2`, overwriting it, instead of creating a new variable `geov$newdate` as you did in your original question. This is because a new variable is not required for conversion. But if for some reason you really need a new variable, feel free to use `geov$newdate`
- similarly, you also didn't need to copy `dusted` to a new `geov` data frame just to convert. It does save time for testing purposes though, just in case the conversion doesn't work you can restart from copying `dusted` to `geov` instead of having to re-import data from a file into `dusted`

### Additional resources

- `help(strptime)` for looking up date code references such as `%y`. On Linux, `man date` can reveal the date codes

Comment: Thanks @ user454038, that was also very helpful and thanks for the reference.