# How To Change the Date format in a df

Tags: r, dataframe, date

I have this date format: 2016-04-14 and I want to change it to 14/4/16
This seems like a simple task but for some reason my strategy is not working. Here is my code:
''''
df$Date <- as.Date(df$Date,format = "%d/%m/%y")
''''

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Changing date format in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7439977/changing-date-format-in-r)

Comment: `lubridate` package can be handy dealing with dates

Comment: You may need to change to character first, and then to date: `as.Date(as.character(df$Date), format = "%d/%m/%y")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want date in specific format use `format` :

```
format(as.Date(df$Date), "%d/%m/%y")
```