# How do I subtract date columns in R when date format is not recognized?

Tags: r, excel, dataframe, date, type-conversion

I have tried the following methods beforehand, without success:

[Changing date format in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7439977/changing-date-format-in-r)

```
t1$date <- dmy(t1$date_admission)
```

I have been trying to calculate the difference in time between two columns. Somehow, R does not recognize the format Y-m-d in one of them and returns me a wrong value, as it follows:

```
> [1] "2020-06-07" "2020-09-07" "2020-02-08" "2020-08-15" "2020-08-15" "2020-08-18" "2020-08-25" "2020-08-29" "2020-06-30"
[10] "2020-05-07" "2020-07-15" "2020-08-14" "2020-01-09" "2020-09-09" "2020-12-09" "2020-02-07" "2020-09-07" "2020-02-08"
[19] "2020-08-15" "2020-02-09" "2020-06-07" "2020-06-07" "2020-07-29" "2020-08-16" "2020-08-21" "2020-08-22" "2020-01-07"
[28] "2020-04-07" "2020-02-07" "2020-01-09" "2020-06-07" "2020-09-08" "2020-10-08" "2020-08-14" "2020-08-27" "2020-08-30"
[37] "2020-07-16" "2020-07-23" "2020-09-14" "2020-01-07" "2020-04-07" "2020-07-07" "2020-07-07" "2020-10-07" "2020-07-25"
[46] "2020-03-08" "2020-08-31" "2020-02-07" "2020-06-07" "2020-08-13" "2020-08-24" "2020-01-07" "2020-07-18" "2020-09-15"
[55] "2020-01-07" "2020-07-07" "2020-07-17" "2020-07-27" "2020-08-14" "2020-10-09" "2020-09-14" "2020-04-08" "2020-01-07"
[64] "2020-01-07" "2020-12-07" "2020-07-27" "2020-04-08" "2020-08-16" "2020-02-07" "2020-07-07" "2020-07-20" "2020-08-19"
[73] "2020-03-09" "2020-05-09"

> print(df$data_inicio_sint)
 [1] "2020-06-27" NA           "2020-07-29" NA           "2020-07-31" "2020-08-19" "2020-08-22" "2020-08-18" "2020-06-29"
[10] "2020-06-25" "2020-07-14" "2020-05-09" "2020-01-10" "2020-08-31" "2020-08-30" "2020-06-28" "2020-09-08" "2020-07-23"
[19] "2020-12-09" "2020-08-22" "2020-04-08" "2020-06-25" "2020-07-20" "2020-08-16" "2020-12-09" "2020-08-23" "2020-06-30"
[28] "2020-06-26" "2020-03-31" "2020-08-23" "2020-06-21" "2020-07-29" "2020-07-29" "2020-08-01" "2020-08-19" "2020-08-14"
[37] "2020-06-30" "2020-07-22" "2020-09-10" "2020-07-01" "2020-02-08" "2020-06-08" "2020-06-23" "2020-06-27" "2020-07-17"
[46] "2020-07-29" "2020-08-31" "2020-06-20" "2020-03-08" "2020-02-09" "2020-08-24" "2020-01-08" "2020-06-08" "2020-10-10"
[55] "2020-06-23" "2020-05-08" "2020-10-08" "2020-07-24" "2020-07-09" "2020-08-29" "2020-10-10" "2020-02-09" "2020-06-23"
[64] "2020-06-22" "2020-08-08" "2020-07-21" "2020-07-28" "2020-05-09" "2020-06-19" "2020-07-08" "2020-07-14" "2020-10-09"
[73] "2020-01-10" "2020-12-09"

> diff(df$data_int_uti - df$data_inicio_sint)
Time differences in days
 [1]   NA   NA   NA   NA  -16    4    8  -10  -50   50   96  -98   10   92 -243  141 -165   50  -79  255  -78   27   -9
[24] -110  109 -174   95   27 -174  213   55   30  -58   -5    8    0  -15    3 -180  235  -30  -15   88  -94 -151  143
[47] -134  225   95 -186   -1   41  -65 -143  228 -143   86   33    5  -67   85 -227    1  288 -115 -117  210 -232  132
[70]    7  -57  110 -273
```

Expected outcome: Time interval between date of symptoms and date of admission in hospital, in days, e.g.

(2020-06-07) - (2020-06-27) =  20 days

So the output would look like
[1] 20
and so on

Any light would be greatly appreciated.

Here's the dput:

> dput(t1)
> structure(list(data_int_uti = structure(c(18420, 18512, 18300,
> 18489, 18489, 18492, 18499, 18503, 18443, 18389, 18458, 18488,
> 18270, 18514, 18605, 18299, 18512, 18300, 18489, 18301, 18420,
> 18420, 18472, 18490, 18495, 18496, 18268, 18359, 18299, 18270,
> 18420, 18513, 18543, 18488, 18501, 18504, 18459, 18466, 18519,
> 18268, 18359, 18450, 18450, 18542, 18468, 18329, 18505, 18299,
> 18420, 18487, 18498, 18268, 18461, 18520, 18268, 18450, 18460,
> 18470, 18488, 18544, 18519, 18360, 18268, 18268, 18603, 18470,
> 18360, 18490, 18299, 18450, 18463, 18493, 18330, 18391), class = "Date"),
> data_inicio_sint = structure(c(18440, NA, 18472, NA, 18474,
> 18493, 18496, 18492, 18442, 18438, 18457, 18391, 18271, 18505,
> 18504, 18441, 18513, 18466, 18605, 18496, 18360, 18438, 18463,
> 18490, 18605, 18497, 18443, 18439, 18352, 18497, 18434, 18472,
> 18472, 18475, 18493, 18488, 18443, 18465, 18515, 18444, 18300,
> 18421, 18436, 18440, 18460, 18472, 18505, 18433, 18329, 18301,
> 18498, 18269, 18421, 18545, 18436, 18390, 18543, 18467, 18452,
> 18503, 18545, 18301, 18436, 18435, 18482, 18464, 18471, 18391,
> 18432, 18451, 18457, 18544, 18271, 18605), class = "Date")), row.names = c(NA,
> -74L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

Comment: There you go. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`diff` is the wrong function to calculate difference between dates. You can directly subtract the dates.

```
t1$date_admission - t1$date_symptoms
#Time differences in days
# [1]  -20   NA -172   NA   15   -1    3   11    1  -49    1   97   -1    9  101
#[16] -142   -1 -166 -116 -195   60  -18    9    0 -110   -1 -175  -80  -53 -227
#[31]  -14   41   71   13    8   16   16    1    4 -176   59   29   14  102    8
#[46] -143    0 -134   91  186    0   -1   40  -25 -168   60  -83    3   36   41
#[61]  -26   59 -168 -167  121    6 -111   99 -133   -1    6  -51   59 -214
```

You might be trying to use `difftime` :

```
difftime(t1$date_admission, t1$date_symptoms, units = "days")
```

---

`diff` function subtracts consecutive values. See for example :

```
diff(c(5, 9, 4, 5))
#[1]  4 -5  1
```

where the calculation is `(9 - 5 = 4)`, `(4 - 9 = -5)` and `(5 - 4 = 1)`. In your case you are first subtracting the dates and then taking applying `diff` on them to get difference between consecutive numbers.

Comment: Hey. I have tried using ```diftime``` and ```t1$date_admission - t1$date_symptoms```, but none of it worked. Both of them return exactly the same values as the one in the post (-20, NA, -172 and so on)

Comment: @dairelix Can you update your post with the expected output.

Comment: The `dput` which you have shared is different from the data that you have shown. `t1$date_admission[1]` is `"2020-06-07"` in your data whereas you have shown it as `(2020-08-07) `

Comment: My bad. Can you please check once again? I believe I have mistakenly used ``select()```.

Comment: Can you check your data again as well? `t1$data_int_uti[1]` is still `"2020-06-07"`. Nothing has changed in the data.

Comment: I finally found my mistake. I'm so sorry, there are multiple similar columns and I've filtered the wrong ones.

Comment: @dairelix For me  `t1$data_inicio_sint - t1$data_int_uti` gives `20   NA  172   NA  -15 ....` Isn't that what you want? and same numbers with `difftime`.

Comment: I see, I was using the wrong column. That's such a stupid mistake of mine. I'm sorry. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

one solution is with dplyr and converting to date

```
library(dplyr)
# example data
t1 <- data.frame(date_admission = c("2020-08-07","2020-07-31","2020-02-08","2020-08-15","2020-08-17","2020-08-24","2020-08-27","2020-10-09","2020-01-07"),
             date_symptoms = c( "2020-06-27", NA           ,"2020-07-29", NA          , "2020-07-31", "2020-08-19", "2020-08-22", "2020-08-18", "2020-06-29"))

# calculation (convert all columns to date and substract according to your example)
t1 %>% 
   dplyr::mutate_all(~ as.Date(.)) %>% 
   dplyr::mutate(DIF = date_admission - date_symptoms)
```