# Convert MM-DD-YYYY into MonthName-DD-YYYY

Tags: r, date

How to convert 10-03-2021 into October-03-2021?

I have column in data frame in MM-DD-YYYY which needs to be converted into Month Name- Date- Year

example

`10-03-2021` into `October-03-2021`

Comment: Do you mean `October-03-2021`?. Refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7439977/changing-date-format-in-r

Comment: You can do: `format(Sys.Date(), format = "%B-%d-%Y")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two parts: parsing the date, and then printing it with your format.

Parsing is quite easy with the [lubridate](https://lubridate.tidyverse.org/) package:

```r
> library(lubridate)
> dates <- mdy(c('10-03-2021', '01-31-1995'))
> dates
[1] "2021-10-03" "1995-01-31"
```

For printing, you can then use the `format()` function:

```r
> format(dates, '%B-%d-%Y')
[1] "October-03-2021" "January-31-1995"
```

`%B` is the full name of the month, `%d` the day and `%Y` the year (with all 4 digits)